# React Native - While inserting image got 500 error

Tags: react-native

Let me tell you i am totally new into react native and in fact this is my first app which i am building. I am dying by this annoying error . This error comes whenever i am adding any image to my project . The syntax i am using is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.splashlogo}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../images/splashscreenlogo.png')}
          />            
          <Text>
            Modeloca
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

but getting this error

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false' failed to load.

Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false' failed to load.
loadApplicationScript
    WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor.java:173
run
    NativeRunnable.java
handleCallback
    Handler.java:739
dispatchMessage
    Handler.java:95
dispatchMessage
    MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31
loop
    Looper.java:135
run
    MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194
run
    Thread.java:818
```

any suggestion!

Comment: Can you show folder of image structure

Comment: ^ yup, as @digit stated, OP should make sure the path of the image is correct.

Comment: If the path is correct, try restarting the packager

Comment: Thanks for all your comments but thats the issue with the package of react native when i upgraded it everything works fine :)